# Cant get the ABI and Interface of solidity code

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract

I am learning solidity following a course. I am completely noob at solidity . I am trying to run my compile.js file using command "node compile.js" .But I am getting same error saying

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()"

I have tried mulitiple solution to fix this . I did match my solidity version with compiler version . After trying multiple solution ,it seems not to work . Dont know where I am missing the spot .

Here is my compile.js file :

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol': {
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*'],
            },
        },
    },
};

module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts['Inbox.sol'].Inbox;
```

My main contract code :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 ;

contract inboxx {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) {
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^4.6.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
}
```

Dont want to quit here . Thanks a lot .

Comment: `solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))` is not valid JSON would be my assumption without running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to the version of your solc.

try that instead:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

const input = {
    'Inbox.sol': source
};
const str = JSON.stringify(input);
const compiled = solc.compile({ sources: input }, 1);
module.exports = {
    abi: compiled.contracts['Inbox.sol:Inbox'].bytecode,
    bytecode: compiled.contracts['Inbox.sol:Inbox'].interface,
}
```

notice the change in the constructor adding the `public` keyword

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) public{
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Check this similar question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950041/2124936

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching , I have change my code to yours ,now its showing error saying "Maximum call stack size exceeded" in VS terminal

Comment: I ran the code here and it is running normally. It is hard to tell what is going on without the stack trace of the error

Comment: My VS terminal showing this error :

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.$db [as dynCall_viiiiii] (G:\Course\inbox\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:12:120931)
    at invoke_viiiiii (G:\Course\inbox\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:1118207)
    at Array.pva (G:\Course\inbox\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:13:29030)
    at Object.M9a [as dynCall_vi] (G:\Course\inbox\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:12:99033)
    at invoke_vi (G:\Course\inbox\inbox\node_modules\solc\soljson.js:1:1115011)
   

my vs terminal showing this error

Comment: try to run on node version v16.17.0

Comment: It seems to be an issue with solc js (https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/537) another possible way would be to run with the command: node --stack-size=2000 compile.js

Comment: That helps , thank you so much 
One more quiry by any chance , can I define the stack size inside the program or any VS setting regarding this or it just the node version that I have to update ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can define it in your vs code as an argument when running your code

Answer (score 0):

you should do this instead.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        [inboxPath] : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}; 
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = {
  abi: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]["Inbox"].abi,
  bytecode: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]["Inbox"].evm.bytecode.object,
};
```

Hope this helps!